# Moving zope.formlib forms from Plone 3 to Plone 4

Tags: user-interface, plone, zope, kss

I've moved from Plone 3.1 to Plone 4.1 a site using zope.formlib for a number of non-archetypes content types, and including some customizations of the widgets.

Now I notice several changes in the layout of the edit forms, such as:

- a tooltip replacing the field description (formHelp class)
- larger text boxes, exceeding the border of the page body
- duplicate descriptions in the checkbox widgets.

Since I'm not able to find relevant changes in the python modules and the page templates, I suspect that said changes mostly depend on the kss machinery, I'm not familiar with.

Any suggestions on what to focus on, in trying to obviate undesired changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take the opportunity and to switch from zope.formlib to the most up to date z3c.form.

More info:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.form
- http://packages.python.org/z3c.form/
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.z3cform